SQL Server Browser service starts up and then immediately turns itself off
I have two servers on SQL Server 2019 that randomly decided to stop the SQL Server Browser service. When attempting to restart it, it turns itself back off immediately. Using the command prompt below to start in console mode on the database host server for more feedback, I see that it is starting up successfully, but gets to the point "Found no installed SQL engine instances -- not listening on SSRP." which is where it shuts itself down again.
C:\Windows\system32>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Shared\sqlbrowser.exe" -c
SQLBrowser: starting up in console mode
SQLBrowser: starting up SSRP redirection service
SQLBrowser is successfully listening on ::[1434]
SQLBrowser is successfully listening on 0.0.0.0[1434]
SQLBrowser: Found no installed SQL engine instances -- not listening on SSRP.
SQLBrowser: Both SSRP and OLAP redirection services are disabled. Shutting down browser service

The only info I can find on this references the missing or disabled registry key for SSRP, which I have already verified is correctly in place.
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\90\SQL Browser\SSRPListener

Key is set to a value of 1. To validate, I set it to 0, at which point SQL Browser doesn't start up at all. Returning to 1, it returns to the original behavior of starting successfully and then shutting itself off immediately.
Meanwhile the databases themselves are accessible, so I know there ARE in fact installed SQL engine instances that should be visible/listening, and I'm completely baffled on how to move forward here. Any slim shred of an idea would be appreciated.
Edit to add screenshot, left side is SQL Server 2019 where it broke, with SQL Server 2014 where it's still working as expected on the right.



SQLBrowser: Found no installed SQL engine instances

Looks like someone or something corrupted the registry on that/those machines. Your best option is to run a repair on each instance on the machine.
Obtaining a procmon or checking the registry manually should show there are no results returned from a query of the registry under the SQL Server Instance key, which is why you're receiving this message.

Both instance names come back correctly from the registry. Verified with powershell:
Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL'

@Ashlin Attach a procmon capture of browser (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon)

You put me on the right track, thanks!

Found the problem. Despite being a 64 bit OS with 64 bit SQL Server instances, SQL Browser was starting up looking for InstalledInstances in the 32 bit registry area.
Was able to fix the problem by removing InstalledInstances from Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server
As it then properly pulled instance names from the 64 bit registry area. Essentially, a registry key existed that shouldn't have been there at all.
